# How to use CursorWrapper to filter Cursor rows

Tags: android, filter, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I want to filter out some rows returned by a Cursor based on a specific condition (which I want to test after receiving the rows from the database, because it's not easy to add it to a WHERE clause in the SQL query). I found the following related questions: 
[Filter rows from Cursor so they don't show up in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027428/filter-rows-from-cursor-so-they-dont-show-up-in-listview), 
[Filtering a cursor the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766688/filtering-a-cursor-the-right-way?rq=1), and [How to hide specific rows of a Cursor in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700172/how-to-hide-specific-rows-of-a-cursor-in-android). I want to implement exactly what those questions are asking.

While the answers to those questions show how to implement a CursorWrapper (which I have done), I don't know how to then link that CursorWrapper to the Cursor & CursorAdapter. The answers just say "Then, use your CursorWrapper in the SimpleCursorAdapter" - can someone elaborate on what this means? Specifically, where do you instantiate the CursorWrapper class and how do you use it in conjunction with the CursorAdapter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CursorWrapper` implements the `Cursor` interface, so you can pass your `CursorWrapper` to your `CursorAdapter` in place of your `Cursor`.